# Combine multiple sql queries into a single sql query in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 3 different PostgreSQL queries, `getUsers`, `getCompanies`, `getEvents` for my homepage. I want to create a single query for this.

My 3 simplified queries:

```
getUsers = SELECT * FROM users;
getCompanies = SELECT * FROM companies;
getEvents = SELECT * FROM events;
```

I want to get an array of objects with this query.
What I tried so far:

```
SELECT
  coalesce(json_agg(users), '[]'::json) as users,
  coalesce(json_agg(companies), '[]'::json) as companies,
  coalesce(json_agg(events), '[]'::json) as events
    FROM
    (
     SELECT
       *
     FROM
       users
    ) AS users,
    (
      SELECT
       *
     FROM
       companies
    ) AS companies,
    (
    SELECT
      *
    FROM
      events
     ) AS events;
```

For a single query this works fine:

```
SELECT
  coalesce(json_agg(companies), '[]'::json) as companies
FROM
  (SELECT
    *
   FROM
    companies
    ) as companies
```

Output is for this single query:

```
companies [
  {
    name: 'test company',
    url: 'https://www.example.com/test-company',
  },
  {
    name: 'test agency',
    url: 'https://www.example.com/test-agency',
  }
]
```

RESULT should be:

```
users: [{...},{...}], 
companies: [{...},{...}], 
events: [{...},{...}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
  coalesce(json_agg(companies), '[]'::json) as companies
FROM
  (SELECT
    *
   FROM
    companies
    ) as companies

UNION
SELECT 
coalesce(json_agg(users), '[]'::json) as users 
FROM 
   (
     SELECT
       *
     FROM
       users
    ) AS users
UNION
SELECT 
coalesce(json_agg(events), '[]'::json) as events 
FROM 
   (
    SELECT
      *
    FROM
      events
     ) AS eventsl
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution after a little bit of struggle. Thanks to nikhil sugandh for putting me on the right path!

```
SELECT
 (jsonb_agg(companies)) as result

FROM
  (SELECT
    *
   FROM
    companies
    ) as companies

UNION
SELECT 
(jsonb_agg(users)) as users  
FROM 
   (
     SELECT
       *
     FROM
       users
    ) AS users
UNION
SELECT 
(jsonb_agg(events)) as events
FROM 
   (
    SELECT
      *
    FROM
      events
     ) AS events
```

[Here the link to the DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/b6pvfaZwjjBtS8rAsuVq8u/21)